# Timer should starts and ends for each element in forloop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game. There are 6 players in the game. I want to start timer for each players turn.

```
$("#startgame").click(function() {
  $(".player").each(function() {
    $(".progressTimer").progressTimer({
      timeLimit: 20,
      warningThreshold: 10,
      baseStyle: 'progress-bar-warning',
      warningStyle: 'progress-bar-danger'
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that a timer starts only one time and the loop executes without previous element animation stops.
And if one player play his turn in between his time interval. how could i stop his timer or clear his time interval and start the timer for next player

Comment: It appears from your example code  that you are using the same `id` for each players timer, this is wrong. The `id` property of an HTML element should always be unique, if you need to do the timer starting generically, then you should give each timer the same className. Also, post the relevant HTML.

Comment: each player(div) have class "player".. its not id

Comment: `$("#progressTimer").progressTimer({` is the same id for each timer element.

Comment: but its a div where countdoewn timer is displaying

Comment: I found that for loop is synchronous and animation is asynchronous in jquery

Comment: you don't seem to understand what I am telling you, if you have 6 timer elements and each one's `id` is progressTimer, when you call `$("#progressTimer").progressTimer' it will only start the first one with that `id`.

Comment: I want to use one timer for every player in game. just start and end  for 30 sec for each player in game.

Comment: Exactly, and since you need 6 different timers, you should have 6 unique ids

Comment: ok  thank you ..i am trying

Comment: If you post your HTML for the six player elements and their timers, I may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

**Question I:** *"How to execute the animation six times with single progress bar?"*

You are right on **for loop is synchronous and animation is asynchronous**.

In the case that you only have one timer, not until the previous animation finishes, the next animation starts.

To fix this, you need to define a global varibale `var i=0;`, and add one more parameter in `progressTimer`, such as `progressTimer({...},i)`. At the end of function `progressTimer`, increment `i++`, `if(i<6)`, call itself again. So that you can make sure next animation executes by the time the previous animation finishes.

**Code Example:**

I found the source code link here [progressTimer](https://github.com/tnory56/jquery-progressTimer). Now I'm gonna demostrate my idea by modifying the code under `jquery-progressTimer/demo/index.html`.

**This is the code sample by original author:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="loading-progress"></div>
</div>
<script src="js/static.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/jquery.progresstimer.js"></script>
<script>
    var progress = $(".loading-progress").progressTimer({
        timeLimit: 10,
        onFinish: function () {
            alert('completed!');
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
       url:"http://localhost/"
    }).error(function(){
        progress.progressTimer('error', {
            errorText:'ERROR!',
            onFinish:function(){
                alert('There was an error processing your information!');
            }
        });
    }).done(function(){
        progress.progressTimer('complete');
    });
</script>
```

Don't worry about the ajax code, because it's just showing when you can't get such a url, progress bar will finish the animation and alert an error. Hence, I  comment out the ajax code because it has nothing to do with our case.

**This is the code after I modified to make the progress bar process 6 times:**

```
var i=0;    
function fn() {
    var progress = $(".loading-progress").progressTimer({
        timeLimit: 5,
        /* onFinish() gurantees when the animation finishes */
        onFinish: function () {
            i++;
            alert('completed!');
            if(i<6){
                fn();
            }
        }
    });
}
fn();
```

Now we are done!

---

**Question II:**

*"if one player play his turn in between his time interval.. how could i stop his timer or clear his time interval and start the timer for next player."*

Here is the second version based on sample code:

```
var i=0;    
var myVar;
function fn() {
    /*Player Initial state in this turn*/
    var PlayerEndHisTurn=false;
    /*Init seconds that past*/
    var secondsPast=0;

    /*Init progress animation*/
    var progress = $(".loading-progress").progressTimer({
        timeLimit: 5,
        warningThreshold: 5,
        onFinish: function () {
            i++;
            alert('completed!');
            if(i<6){
                fn();                                   
            }
        }
    }); 

    /*We keep track of time every second*/
    myVar=setInterval(function(){
        secondsPast++;
        //console.log(secondsPast);

        /*Assume every player end his turn on the third second*/
        if(secondsPast==3){
            PlayerEndHisTurn=true;
        }
        /*If the player ends his turn*/
        if(PlayerEndHisTurn){
            /*Progress bar skips this player's turn, call complete*/
            /*No need to call i++ because we called this in onFinish()*/
            //i++;
            progress.progressTimer('complete');
            /*Stop timing for this player*/
            clearInterval(myVar);
            /*Prevent multiple interval function running*/
            return myVar;
            /*Start the next player's turn*/
            fn();
        }
        /*if the player runs out his time*/
        if(secondsPast==5){             
            clearInterval(myVar);
            return myVar;
        }
    },1000);
}
fn();
```

Comment: actually value of i increases but it is not waiting for timer to be finished for first i.  so timer works for only time in loop.         
function timer(i){
    //timer code 
      i++;
      if(i<6){
        console.log(i);
        timer(i);
      }
}

Comment: Can you share more of your code, like the code block for `progressTimer`?

Comment: I am using jquery plugin( jquery.progressTimer.js ) for progress timer. And here is the link "https://github.com/tnory56/jquery-progressTimer"

Comment: I want timer should start and end for  6 no of time but sequentially one by one.

Comment: I can't access the link you provided :(

Comment: Hi mate, I found the link already and have edit the answer :)

Comment: No worries, my pleasure. Please don't forget to accept my answer, thanks :)

Comment: I have one question again.. if one player play his turn in between his time interval.. how could i stop his timer or clear his time interval and start the timer for next player.

Comment: give me a sec, I will post the solution in my answer

Comment: Can you add this additional questions to your original post? So it would be clear with what I am answering to

Comment: Edit my answer, please check :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, I comment out `i++` under `if(PlayerEndHisTurn)`, and I've added the reason above as well

Comment: hi ,  myVar function is in fn function. it is working but i want  to call that function by clicking another button.at that time i dont want to call fn function ..only need of  myvar  . so how could i call it?

Comment: Is your goal to make a player pass his turn by clicking a button? If that's so, you can take `PlayerEndHisTurn` out of `fn()`, if the button is clicked, set `PlayerEndHisTurn` to `true`, but remember to reset it to `false` under `if(PlayerEndHisTurn)` and `if(secondsPast==5){`